# Candy webclient with Openfire, not working complete

Tags: xmpp, openfire, livechat, chatroom, candy

I have set up the Openfire xmpp server and it's running good from a client, but i want to use candy with it to create a chatroom (muc), my settings in openfire work and so there is a conference.blabla.nl, that conference server i can connect with Pandion and Tkabber, i log in and ask what rooms are there or if i want to create one myself, that all go well.

When i connect with candy it only connects as i use a proper login name and pass, but i want it to join or create a chatroom on  the muc.
When i login with proper username and pass my screen gets grey, but when i type something to the user logged in at candy there will appear that there are messages but only then, i can't read them in candy...

So to go short, i have candy up and running but shows only information when someone sends something.

Anyone knows about it or have some good tips what could work.
I just want a webclient that people can use with a own chosen name like "guest" or something and then log in to the chatroom.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possible options:

1. On initialization of Candy, specify autojoin with "true" and in the openfire server specify autojoin bookmarks.
2. On initialization of Candy, specify autojoin with an array of rooms to autojoin
3. use the [roomPanel Plugin](https://github.com/candy-chat/candy-plugins/tree/master/roomPanel) to discover existing rooms and be able to join them.

Btw. we have a [support mailinglist as well](http://groups.google.com/group/candy-chat)

Comment: You can always ask on the mailinglist, we'll usually answer there faster.